# Scroll the page to show the active row

Tags: excel, vba, scroll, row

I am doing my calculation and using VBA. When I run the code I can not see what is happening, let's say in line 400, till the end of run.

I found this code:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Selection.Row 
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = Selection.Column
```

or

```
Application. Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow,True
```

How do I scroll the page and show the active row while code is running?

Comment: Try adding `DoEvents` after the Goto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below it will auto move to the active cell

```
Sub test()
    Dim i as Long    
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Range("A" & i).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to goto Row 400?

```
Application.Goto  Rows(400)
```

If you want to pause execution you can use `Stop` or `Debug.Assert False`

```
For i = 0 to to lastRow

    If i = 400 then 
        Application.Goto Rows(400)
        Stop
    End IF

Next
```

If you want pause the macro is a condition is true then use `Debug.Assert False`.  Note: Debug.Assert pauses the code when the condition is false.

```
For i = 0 to to lastRow

    Debug.Assert i <> 400 

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control it like that:

```
Private Sub seid_Change() 
    If seid.Value = 1 Then 
        wsM.Range ("A125").Select 
        Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True 
    ElseIf seid.Value = 2 Then 
        wsM.Range ("A128").Select
        Application.Goto <br>ActiveCell.EntireRow, True 
    End If 
End sub
```